# UDP sockets - server not receiving any data

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu, udp

I am trying to develop a UDP client-server program. Here's my code:

**Server**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in client, server;
    int s, i=0;
    socklen_t n;
    char buf[4];
    s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=atoi(argv[1]);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "localhost", &(server.sin_addr));
    bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server));
    n=sizeof(client);

    while(1) {
        recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &n);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

**Client**

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in client, server;
    int s, n;
    char buf[30];
    char temp[4];
    s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=atoi(argv[2]);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &(server.sin_addr));

    n=sizeof(server);

    while(1) {
        scanf("%s", buf);
        fflush(stdin);
        sendto(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server, n);
    }
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Fairly basic in nature without any error handling. Server outputs whatever the client sends.

It stopped working on my Ubuntu machine after I forgot to delete/free my dynamically allocated memory when I was testing something. It works perfectly fine on a different Linux server.

Any idea what could be causing this? Unclosed ports, memory leaks? How do I fix this?

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*, so do not use it.

Comment: `printf("%s", buf);` may also invoke *undefined behavior* if what is in `buf` is not null-terminated string. Terminate the "string" properly before printing, or print in another way.

Comment: Previously, my program was stuck at not being able to read the data, so I had to force clean the stdin buffer. Any better alternative?

Comment: I am trying to send:
`temp[0] = 't';
temp[1] = 'e';
temp[2] = 'm';
temp[3] = '\0';`
still does not work.

Comment: "without any error handling". You really shouldn't post here until you have done these basics. It's not a productive use of community time. If you add in error checking it may help you solve the problem yourself or at least point you or us closer to where the problem may lie.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your approach:

- `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior.  If you want to read and discard the rest of the line entered by the user, use this:

  ```
  scanf("%*[^\n]");  /* consume all remaining chars on the line, if any */
  scanf("%*c");      /* consume the linefeed if any */
  ```
- The client code should just send the string, possibly with a separator, but not the full buffer, parts of which are uninitialized:

  ```
  sendto(s, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, n);
  ```
- The server code should null terminate the buffer received from the client:

  ```
  while(1) {
      ssize_t nr = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &n);

      if (nr >= 0) {
          buf[nr] = '\0';
          printf("%s", buf);
      }
  }
  ```
- Both the client and the server should handle end of file and system call failures gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @kaylum mentioned, you need to check for errors. Beyond that, I see several problems:

- `inet_pton()` does not convert a hostname to an address. Normally, you
  don't want to bind to a specific IP address on the server side
  anyway; instead, set it to `INADDR_ANY`. On the client side, 127.0.0.1 will work for sending to a server on the same machine.
- You need to convert your port number to network byte order with
  `htons()`.
- You're sending 30 bytes but your receive buffer is only 4 bytes long.
  It has been mentioned that you shouldn't send the whole 30-byte
  buffer, but that's up to you and your protocol. You just have to be
  able to handle whatever is being sent.
- As others have mentioned, `fflush(stdin)` is incorrect; `fflush()` is used
  for flushing output, but `stdin` is an input file.
- `scanf("%s", buf)` does not limit the input to the size of the buffer,
  so that might cause a problem. Use `fgets()` instead.